# Uninterruptible Power Supply for Intel Nuc?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-bank, ups

My town suffers from quite a few power outages as of late and I am running a home server via my Intel NUC. I'm looking for recommendations on the type of UPS I could buy for such a device. Typically I'd like a supply which could last 3 hours (based on our average time for power resolution).

Are there any recommendations you could give?

Comment: What other items would you be running from the UPS, or is it purely to keep the NUC powered on? Would a UPS which tells the computer to shut down when the battery is nearly empty be a useful feature?

Comment: Just the NUC itself. I'm open to options in regards to your 2nd point. It would be nice for a graceful shutdown near the end of battery life.

Comment: imho this has nothing to do with power banks. maybe remove the power-bank tag?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [openUPS2](http://www.mini-box.com/OpenUPS2) or NUC-UPS from mini-box.com, they even have hard drive mounting footprint for easy integration with case. They also send ON/OFF pulse to the motherboard via 2 wire or USB for graceful shutdown.